# How to validate emails onEqual in several divs with them on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

The situation:

```
<body>
    <div id="1">
      <input type="text" name="email_1"/>
      <input type="text" name="email_2"/>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
      <input type="text" name="email_3"/>
      <input type="text" name="email_4"/>
    </div>
    <!--and so on...-->
</body>
```

And I need to validate inputs inside these 2 inputs inside every div to be equal(only inside div). Maybe the main problem is that all divs are dynamically generated, and we don't know exactly their quantity to provide knockout support. How to do that? What is the most elegant solution?

**Update 1**

I've tried:
 1. To make some binding using knockout model. But my solution for this
    was to create some observable property to check inputs values. This
    is bad way I guess.
 2. To use jquery for this. Tried to validate fields via validate class for
    inputs(http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/)

**Update 2**

My solution was something like that:

```
<div id="1">
   <input type="text" name="email_1"/>
   <input type="text" name="email_2"/>
   <label data-bind="visible: checkEmailsEquality(email_1,email_2)">Emails must be equal</label>
</div>
```

But this solution is not ok, because this binding works only once - at page loading, what isn't good. I need to bind this check to text update in these inputs, and I don't know how.

**Update 3**

My suggestion is to deal with it in this way:

1. Make on the first email input this binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html
2. Bind with similar function in knockout's model as wrote Wayne Ellery.
3. If values aren't equal make error label visible.
4. The main condition is to pass apropriate inputs ids to function, and I guess this will work.

Comment: I think you misunderstood Flynn's comment.  Show us the relevant code you need help fixing.  Do not expect us to write everything for you.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I'll show you my knockout try. So, the idea  is to pass to knockout's model function inputs ids and check their values.(see my updated question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found maybe the most elegant solution, it's about using equalTo attribute, e.g.:

```
<div id="1">
  <input type="text" id="1" name="email_1" equalTo="#2"/>
  <input type="text" id="2" name="email_2" equalTo="#1"/>
</div>
```

Hope this help somebody.

Comment: What is this equalTo attribute? I couldn't find any information about it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to just use a computed which will compare the two emails.

Below in ViewModel I'm using the jQuery $.map method to map all items to an array of Item objects.

```
var ViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = $.map(model.items, function(item) { return new Item(item) });
};
```

Here I'm using a computed method in Item to compare email1 and email2.

```
var Item = function (item) {
    var self = this;

    self.email1 = ko.observable(item.email1);
    self.email2 = ko.observable(item.email2);

    self.areEmailsSame = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.email1() === self.email2();
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxar0587/1/

Comment: Your solution is fine, but quantity of div elements is unknown. Divs are generated on the page due to particular conditions. Once we have 1 div, another time we have 10 divs.

Comment: Ok. This was not clear in the question. I'll update my solution to be dynamic